# Build failed while deploying cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have a python code to move files from one bucket to another bucket. However, I can't able to deploy the code.

[image: I am getting the following error:]

This is my requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage
zipfile
datetime
os
```

And my main.py

```
from google.cloud import storage
import zipfile
import datetime
import os
```

The 'google-cloud-storage' package is already exists but still my deployment is failing. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Remove `zipfile`, `datetime` and `os` from requirements.txt and try again. Do not specify built-in packages in the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, sometimes the package already exists and we receive this error, so try to see whether you can import it or not.

As John Henley suggested in the comment, you need not to specify the `zipfile` manually. [Zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) is in the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/#:%7E:text=zipfile%20%E2%80%94%20Work%20with%20ZIP%20archives). `import zipfile` in `main.py` should work fine.  Also remove `datetime` and `os` from `requirements.txt` file as john suggested already in the comment.

Make sure you run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command to install all the required packages.